# Nexus symlink cant see install4j_java_home

Tags: ansible, nexus, symlink, sonatype

I am creating a `symlink` using `Ansible`.

Here is the task that I have created:

```
---

- name: Create nexus symlink
  file:
    src: "/{{ lcp }}/nex/local/lib/nexus/{{ nexus_package }}/bin/nexus"
    path: "/etc/init.d/nexus"
    owner: root
    group: root
    state: link

- name: add nexus service
  command: /sbin/chkconfig --add /etc/init.d/nexus
  args:
    chdir: /etc/init.d

- name: set nexus service level
  command: /sbin/chkconfig --levels 345 nexus on
  args:
    chdir: /etc/init.d

- name: start nexus service
  command: /sbin/service nexus start
  args:
     chdir: /etc/init.d
```

What I have noticed is that `Ansible` runs as `root`. When running my task, I had to point directly to the `/sbin/chkconfig` because it was looking in the `bin` folder.

I have a user called `nexi` that I am running `Nexus` as. My `HOME` directory is located at `/int/nex/nexi`. At this home directory, I can see `-rw-rw-r-- 1 nexi nexi 107 Oct  3 19:48 .install4j`.

In the `/etc/init.d` I can see that my symlink is created `lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    49 Oct  2 14:20 nexus -> /int/nex/local/lib/nexus/nexus-3.4.0-02/bin/nexus`.

When I execute `/sbin/service nexus start` from `Ansible`, then I am getting

`No suitable Java Virtual Machine could be found on your system.\nThe version of the JVM must be at least 1.8 and at most 1.8.\nPlease define INSTALL4J_JAVA_HOME to point to a suitable JVM.`

You can see that I have a `JAVA_HOME`:

```
which java
/int/nex/local/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_131/bin/java
```

And install4j in my `HOME` for `nexi` user

```
cat .install4j
JRE_VERSION /int/nex/local/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_131    1   8   0   131
JRE_INFO    /int/nex/local/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_131    0
```

I have been following Sonatype Nexus [docs](https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/3.0/reference/install.html#service-linux)

I have tried adding a `java.sh` in `/etc/.profile.d` to expose the java locations for `root`. I am no pro here though. This is what I put in the `java.sh`

```
export JAVA_HOME=/int/nex/local/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_131
export PATH=$PATH:/int/nex/local/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_131/bin
```

Answer (score 1):

> You can see that I have a `JAVA_HOME`

Yes. When you run an interactive shell session you can see that (only in interactive shell session). Probably for the same reason your path differs and you had to define absolute paths to the executables.

> I have tried adding a `java.sh` in `/etc/.profile.d` to expose the java locations for root

Which does not have any effect, because Ansible runs shell in non-interactive mode and shell does not source this file (see `man bash` for example).

---

Add `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH` as environment to Ansible modules. See [Setting the Environment](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_environment.html).

Comment: When I am `nexi` on the server and run `service nexus start`, I get the same `INSTALL4J_JAVA_HOME` error as above. Do I need to change the `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH` for all tasks?

Comment: Yes and no. Formally yes, because every single task will run in a separate session. No, because as you can read in the linked doc: “*You can also use it at a play level*”